# Best way of changing authentication mechanism with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, formsauthentication

I need to read, generate and keep updated an authentication cookie that is different from formsauthentication one.

I saw many options like using `IHttpHandlers`, `IHttpModules`, custom Authorization filters, etc.

How would you deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to mess with the authentication cookie, in your Global.asax, use the Application_AuthenticateRequest event

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi. None of them. I need my own mode. It's similar to forms but using a different cookie (another application in the same domain needs to read it)